# When is /etc/crontab executed after a reboot?

Tags: ubuntu, cron

On Ubuntu 18.04 I have a script that seems to only work when in /etc/crontab, instead of the other files.

After a reboot when is /etc/crontab run? Can I trust that the network will be up by then?

Comment: `systemctl list-dependencies cron.service`. I don't see any network dependency on Ubuntu 16.

Comment: my scripts needs the internet working :(

Comment: Crontab is executed relatively early, before various other services are on. If you need to execute at boot, I use `@boot` and a `sleep 20 && ` before script name. Else I put a new service with correct dependencies. Or in your script (if you execute every minute), check if network is on